# Can you determine small primes from larger primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Suppose you are given the primes in the range $[n,n^2]$. Is there a known way to effectively reconstruct the primes less than $n$? Ideally, something that takes less calculation than figuring them out directly from sieving, as that would sort of defeat the purpose.

Heuristically, you can do pretty well by taking $n \pmod{p}$ where $n$ is composite and $p$ steps through your prime list, and then seeing what comes up most often, but I'm hoping for something better than that.

Comment: To find $p<n$, you'd only need to consider integers in $[n,2n]$. That could help some.

Comment: Every prime $p$ less than $n$ should factor some number in $[n,2n]$ that is either 1 more or 1 less than a multiple of 6.

Comment: And multiples of 6. Perhaps Euclid's GCD algorithm can be used some how.

Answer (score -1):

This is very slow compared to e.g. the sieve method. For example with $n=1000$ there are $\pi(10^6)-\pi(10^3) = 78330$ primes in $[n,n^2]$ but only $168$ primes less than $1000$.
So you would do $78330$ modulo operation with your method. For larger $n$ your method would even be worse.

Comment: True, but at this point I'm only shooting for a proof of concept, so that's my starting point. This will never be an efficient way to generate primes, I just wonder whether it's theoretically possible.